# What is wrong with my event timer loop thing?

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

I have a timer set up that should run code every 10th of a second, but instead it seems to run the desired code only once. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. :{

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
                  System.out.println("it only prints this once");
          }
        }, 100, 100000);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `0*0*100` = `0` not an issue per say, just a lot of noise

Comment: You are multiplying the first param by 0, it will always be zero

Comment: I took out the noise, issue still there.

Comment: As I said, it was noise not an issue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two arguments to `scheduleAtFixedRate` seem odd. The first one is always 0 (which is not a problem; just means that there's no delay before the first execution). The second is set to 2 minutes, not 0.1 second. The argument is supposed to be the rate in milliseconds. For 0.1 second, you should use 100, not 2*60*1000.

Try this:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("it only prints this once");
    }
}, 100, 100);
```

Comment: I took out the noise, issue still there.

Comment: @user2619934 - You originally had set up the task to run once every 2 minutes, not once every 1/10 second. It's now set up to run once every 100 seconds (a little faster than once every 2 minutes, but still much more of a delay than you say you want).

Comment: Really? That must be the issue! I thought it was measured in milliseconds.

Comment: @user2619934 - It is measuring milliseconds. 1000 milliseconds is 1 second; 100 milliseconds is 0.1 second. You were coding as if it were microseconds.

Comment: I have it set on 100, 1/10th of a second and it only prints once.

Comment: This will be the accepted answer, setting the second parameter to 100 fixed it.